# Method comparison studies - which method is "better"?

Tags: method-comparison, bland-altman-plot

I have two laboratory methods to measure the same property.  One method is principally instrument based the other is more of a manual method.  I believe in my heart that the instrument-based method is the "better" method.  Since this is a laboratory test I would rather make a decision on this based on something rather more defensible than my feelings.

Based on previous posts here on Cross Validated I purchased Bendix Carstensen's book "Comparing Clinical Measurement Methods" and I read some of the papers written by Bland and Altman.

These papers and books seem to basically be methods of increasing statistical sophistication to describe how to map one method to a second method.  I have yet to find anything in these studies that helps to resolve the question of which method is "better".

To further complicate things, the material I'm testing is not stable with time.  I can expect the results of the analysis to increase as the sample ages.  I believe this is true for both methods.  This make replicates a little tricky.  I also don't have any kind of a gold standard for this analysis.

I have a data set of approximately 2000 paired measurements (one for each method).  I was hoping to be able to statically defend replacing one method with the other.  I have linked this data set and intentionally not indicated which method is instrument based and which method is manual.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W6DA9uZcpHudVFSTgjTv_Kewr8vVaUVQ/view?usp=sharing

I have been looking at these sources for help as well:

https://bendixcarstensen.com/MethComp/introMethComp.pdf

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcr/mcr.pdf

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deming/vignettes/deming.pdf

https://cdn.sanity.io/files/0vv8moc6/biopharn/03ef28d24bbd61112cdbd8750d3b8d3435409c35.pdf/article-7276.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXzzlueX3tw

I've learned some interesting things about handling error in regressions, but I'm not sure that I can really defend the selection of method 1 over method 2 (or method 2 over method 1).

Any help or recommendations of other papers/books to read would be appreciated.